# Java ResultSet getDouble() incorrect values

Tags: java, resultset

When working with **ResultSet getDouble()**, I want to get the correct value from the database.
The value stored in the database is 11.421351.when I do resultSet.getDouble("lon").I get 11.4213599999 like that.
How would I get this to just print 11.421351?

Comment: This may because doubles are stored like that(in java). You may try `getString()`.

Comment: @dan1st That's not the problem here.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

The `double` and `float` types in Java use floating point arithmetic, and are not exact.  Instead, you should be using exact types:

- In Java, use `BigDecimal`
- In your SQL database, use `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`

Then, when you are accessing your result set from Java, use `ResultSet#getBigDecimal` to obtain the number with its full original precision.